# ParametricPlot Incomplete

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I have a problem to reproduce a graph. Follows the commands used:

```
X[r_] = -A Csc[ϕ];
Y[r_] = Sqrt[B + a^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 - A^2 Cot[ϕ]^2];
A = (r^2 (3 M - r) - a^2 (M + r))/(a (r - M));
B = (r^3 (4 a^2 M - r (3 M - r)^2))/(a^2 (r - M)^2);
M = 1; a = 0.79; ϕ = Pi/2;
ParametricPlot[{X[r], Y[r]}, {r, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

However, the graph should be as follows:

[image]

i.e., I haven't been able to close the curve. Someone can help? Some hint?

Comment: simply look at your data ! `Table[{X[r], Y[r]}, {r, 0, 2 Pi, .2 Pi}]` and you'll see it generates complex numbers. Your code is also strange. Why write function `X[r_] = -A Csc[\[Phi]];` when there is no explicit `r` in RHS? but your main problem is your data is complex.

Comment: Thanks by the comments @Nasser. Note that both quantities A and B are defined on the third and fourth row, respectively.

Comment: Do you mean to say X[r_] := and Y[r_] :=?

Comment: @MarkR, these are the functions to be plotted. Both are functions dependent on the variable `r` (see the definition of `A` and `B`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definitions are viable:

```
ClearAll[A,B,ϕ,X, Y]

X[r_] = -A Csc[ϕ];
Y[r_] = Sqrt[B + a^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 - A^2 Cot[ϕ]^2];

A = (r^2 (3 M - r) - a^2 (M + r))/(a (r - M));
B = (r^3 (4 a^2 M - r (3 M - r)^2))/(a^2 (r - M)^2);
M = 1; a = 0.79; ϕ = Pi/2;
```

Now check the domain of your function.

```
dom = FunctionDomain[{Y[r], r > 1}, r, Reals]

(*  1.83298 <= r <= 3.80951  *)
```

Plot both (X,Y) and (X,-Y) over the domain:

```
ParametricPlot[{{X[r], Y[r]}, {X[r], -Y[r]}},
 {r, First@dom, Last@dom}, GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotStyle -> {{Black, Dashed}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

However, the left edge is not as vertical as in the desired plot.

Notice that we had to specify $r>1$ for our domain.  There is a different solution for $r<1$.  We should have specified $r>M$.

Comment: thank you very much! About the left edge, simply set the value `a=0.99` and we will have something like vertical. You have solved my problem, thanks again.